# Pandas - How to pick events by date and create a new ordered dataframe. - surgery patients

Tags: python, pandas

I am a surgeon looking at neurosurgery. I have a dataframe of 600,000 records, and 70 columns with about 7 date columns for various events that happened to patients in a hospital sytem over a 6 year period. 
i
I  am interested in cranial implants to repair the skull.

There are 4000 records from this dataframe that show a code for an operation to either insert or remove an implant. About 900 patients had more than one operation with about 500 insertions and 500 or so removals of implants (for infection etc). I have the dates of the operations as pd.datetime. I have the patients encrypted id.

The 600,000 records span a 6 year period. I need to analyse the 900 who had multiple operations. 
I need to order the operations datewise because this is just a snapshot in time. 
eg a patient could have had an implant put in before the data collection of the snapshot started, then had it removed during the snapshot, then reinserted during in the snapshot. Conversely one could have had the reverse, - insertion and removal during the snapshot. So I want to establish the numbers of removal-insertion , and insertion-removal, - and the time between.

Ideally I'd like a table of patient id as index, with insertion + removal date as fields. i can then calculate the time between.

I am new to python, - can do basic filtering, groupby, crosstab etc but not loops yet. 
many thanks.

```
        ID  OP_code  OPDATE_01

1       xxx V259    2014-12-12
2       xxx A082    2014-06-23
3       999 V011    2014-08-07
4       xxx A023    2014-09-12
... ... ... ...
473231  xxx A651    2018-10-03
473233  999 V014    2018-07-06
473235  xxx A263    2018-05-18
```

Heres some data, the rows are individual episodes of care so the patient ID column is not unique. So above, patient ID 999 had an implant put in (code V011) on 2014-08-07, and then had it taken out (code V014) on 2018-07-06. 
So what I'd like is a table of

```
ID.   OPDATE1.    OP_01_code    OPDATE2.   OP_02_code

999.  2014-08-07.  V011         2018-07-06.  V014
```

To do this I would have to search the 3000 or so individual ID patients in the 4000 record dataframe by ID to get the individual operations for each patient then order them as the table above. Obviously the majority would have only had one operation.

Update
- after @Arne suggestion below.

```
display(df_implants)
                                    OPDATE_01                    OPERTN_01
ENCRYPTED_HESID     
1111                                [2019-01-26]                 [V011]
1112                                [2019-01-22]                 [V011]
1113                                [2015-09-24]                 [V011]
1114                                [2016-06-21, 2017-02-27]     [V011, V014]
1115                                [2018-12-27]                 [V011]
... ... ...
3046                                [2017-02-18]                 [V011]
3047                                [2013-06-08]                 [V011]
```

Comment: can you post a few (randomised) rows of your data?

Comment: thanks, see above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edit:** I've changed the filter criterion below to at least **two** different OPs of interest.

Here is one way to do this. I've changed your data somewhat for testing purposes.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'ID': [1, 2, 999, 3, 1, 999, 2],
                   'OP_code': ['V011', 'A082', 'V011', 'V011', 'A651', 'V014', 'A263'], 
                   'OP_date': ['2014-12-12', '2014-06-23', '2014-08-07', '2014-09-12', 
                               '2018-10-03', '2018-07-06', '2018-05-18']})
df.set_index('ID', inplace=True)
display(df)
```

```
   OP_code     OP_date
ID      
1    V011   2014-12-12
2    A082   2014-06-23
999  V011   2014-08-07
3    V011   2014-09-12
1    A651   2018-10-03
999  V014   2018-07-06
2    A263   2018-05-18
```

First we should transform the data so that there is exactly one row per patient, collecting the data from multiple OPs in lists:

```
df_patients = pd.pivot_table(df, index=df.index, aggfunc=list)
display(df_patients)
```

```
     OP_code        OP_date
ID      
1    [V011, A651]   [2014-12-12, 2018-10-03]
2    [A082, A263]   [2014-06-23, 2018-05-18]
3    [V011]         [2014-09-12]
999  [V011, V014]   [2014-08-07, 2018-07-06]
```

Now given a list of the OP codes that correspond to the implants you're interested in, we can loop through the rows of this DataFrame to create an index of only those patients that had **at least two different OPs of interest**. Then we can filter the data according to this new index.

```
implant_codes = {'V011', 'V014'}

implant_index = []
for i in df_patients.index:
    """EDIT: filter criterion tightened to at least two different 
       relevant OPs, i.e. the intersection of the implant_codes 
       list with the patient's OP list has at least two elements."""
    if len(implant_codes.intersection(df_patients.OP_code[i])) >= 2: 
        implant_index.append(i)

df_implants = df_patients.filter(implant_index, axis=0)
display(df_implants)
```

```
     OP_code       OP_date
ID      
999  [V011, V014]  [2014-08-07, 2018-07-06]
```

You can access data elements here by a combination of the indexing syntax for DataFrames and lists, e.g. `df_implants.loc[999, 'OP_date'][0]` yields the first OP date of patient 999: `'2014-08-07'`

I would not recommend creating a separate column for each OP. You could try something like this:

```
df_implants[['OP_date_1', 'OP_date_2']] = pd.DataFrame(df_implants.OP_date.values.tolist(), 
                                                       index=df_implants.index)
display(df_implants)
```

```
     OP_code       OP_date                   OP_date_1   OP_date_2
ID              
999  [V011, V014]  [2014-08-07, 2018-07-06]  2014-08-07  2018-07-06
```

However, this approach will run into trouble in practice, due to the fact that the number of OPs varies across patients. That's why I think the list representation given above is more natural and easier to handle.

Comment: Thanks - a lot in there.It will take me a while to work through and grasp this, - I may have made a mistake but my df_implants table is the same as my df_patients table (see above), - it appears to have not filtered out only those patients having two operations. Will keep working on it.

Comment: That's my mistake. I forgot you were only interested in patients with at least two relevant OPs. I will update my answer accordingly.

Comment: Thanks, I had previously approached it by separating out a dataframe of patients who had more than one operation using ```df2 = df[df["ID"].duplicated(keep=False)]``` , - but still need to reporganise that.

Comment: When I do some reading and get a good handle on it you will have advanced my learning by about 200% - much appreciated.

Comment: I have used this method a again for a group of patients having multiple operations. However the description of the set ```implant_codes = {'V011', 'V014'}
``` above does not pull out those patients who have the same operation twice. How can I modify the set definition?