# Removing square brackets and apostrophes from a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am a surgeon trying to analyse some patient data.I have a dataframe of patients (271x15) who have had multiple operations. This is from a larger (4010x71) dataframe of single operations using much help from @Arne . Essentially (see post 
[original post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60884042/pandas-how-to-pick-events-by-date-and-create-a-new-ordered-dataframe-surger)) using a pivot table then looking for multiple (>=2) operations. This is great. I am interested in the first two operations and the dates to get the number of days between them to see how long an implant lasted. 
The dataframe head is here and shows the patient ID and the codes (V011 and V014)  for the insetion and removal of the implant.

```
                                 OPERTN_01      OPDATE_01
ID      
11                              [V011, V014]    [2016-06-21, 2017-02-27]
13                              [V011, V014]    [2016-07-14, 2016-01-14]
14                              [V014, V011]    [2014-02-25, 2014-07-01]
15                              [V014, V011]    [2014-06-26, 2015-04-16]
```

I was hoping to subtract the dates of the two operations by

1. Removing the square brackets
2. Splitting the ?tuples into two columns
3. Ensuring the dates are `pd.datetime`
4. Subtracting the two dates.

I am stuck at removing the brackets. I have tried replace `df.replace("[", "")` , which has no effect on the dataframe or on the series `OPERTN_01`. Ideally I would like to remove the square brackets throughout the dataframe rather than column by column.

The lists produced in this dataframe (thanks @Arne ) have produced great descriptive statistics but are difficult for me to manipulate.

I also have the problem that the dates in OPDATE_01 are not sorted so the difference between the dates is often negative. Could be that I am wanting to do too much at one of course..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you looking for something like this:

```
from io import StringIO
import ast
import pandas as pd

# ------ create sample data ------
s = """ID;OPERTN_01;OPDATE_01
11;["V011", "V014"];["2016-06-21", "2017-02-27"]
13;["V011", "V014"];["2016-07-14", "2016-01-14"]
14;["V014", "V011"];["2014-02-25", "2014-07-01"]
15;["V014", "V011"];["2014-06-26", "2015-04-16"]"""

df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(s), sep=';')
df['OPERTN_01'] = df['OPERTN_01'].apply(ast.literal_eval)
df['OPDATE_01'] = df['OPDATE_01'].apply(ast.literal_eval)
df = df.set_index('ID')

# ------ end sample data ------

# list comprehension to sort and convert str to datetime
df['OPDATE_01'] = [sorted([pd.to_datetime(x[0]), pd.to_datetime(x[1])]) for x in df['OPDATE_01']]

# if your values in the list are already datetime then ignore what is above and do
# df['OPDATE_01'] = df['OPDATE_01'].apply(sorted)

# apply pd.Series to explode your list into columns and then rename col if you want
date = df['OPDATE_01'].apply(pd.Series).rename(columns={0:'OPDATE_01_0', 1:'OPDATE_01_1'})
# calculate the difference between dates
date.diff(axis=1)

   OPDATE_01_0 OPDATE_01_1
ID                        
11         NaT    251 days
13         NaT    182 days
14         NaT    126 days
15         NaT    294 days
```

## OR

```
# list comprehension to sort and convert list to datetime
df['OPDATE_01'] = [sorted([pd.to_datetime(x[0]), pd.to_datetime(x[1])]) for x in df['OPDATE_01']]

# if your values in the list are already datetime then ignore what is above and do
# df['OPDATE_01'] = df['OPDATE_01'].apply(sorted)

# apply pd.Series to explode your list into columns and then rename col if you want
date = df['OPDATE_01'].apply(pd.Series).rename(columns={0:'OPDATE_01_0', 1:'OPDATE_01_1'})
# merge two frames on ID to maintain all columns
m = df['OPERTN_01'].to_frame().merge(date, left_index=True, right_index=True)
# calc diff and assign to new column
m['diff'] = m.diff(axis=1)['OPDATE_01_1']

       OPERTN_01 OPDATE_01_0 OPDATE_01_1     diff
ID                                               
11  [V011, V014]  2016-06-21  2017-02-27 251 days
13  [V011, V014]  2016-01-14  2016-07-14 182 days
14  [V014, V011]  2014-02-25  2014-07-01 126 days
15  [V014, V011]  2014-06-26  2015-04-16 294 days
```

## per your comment

```
# just changing variable name to match your comment
df_implants = m

# convert OPERTN_01 to a string
s = df_implants['OPERTN_01'].apply(str)

# boolean indexing to filter df_implants where OPERTN_01 is equal to ['V011', 'V014']
v011v014 = df_implants[(s == "['V011', 'V014']")]

# boolean indexing to filter df_implants where OPERTN_01 is equal to ['V014', 'V011']
v014v011 = df_implants[(s == "['V014', 'V011']")]
```

## v011v014

```
       OPERTN_01 OPDATE_01_0 OPDATE_01_1     diff
ID                                               
11  [V011, V014]  2016-06-21  2017-02-27 251 days
13  [V011, V014]  2016-01-14  2016-07-14 182 days
```

## v014v011

```
       OPERTN_01 OPDATE_01_0 OPDATE_01_1     diff
ID                                               
14  [V014, V011]  2014-02-25  2014-07-01 126 days
15  [V014, V011]  2014-06-26  2015-04-16 294 days
```

Comment: Both are tremendous, - Will take me a while to work through but very clear and has taught me a lot thanks.

Comment: Great, glad it helped. Let me know if you need any of the pandas/python operations explained further.

Comment: I am struggling to filter the resultant lists. I would like to create new dataframes of the ordered operations ```[V011, V014]```, and``` [V014, V011]```. I have tried ```df_implants['OPDATE_01'].str.findall('[V011, V014]')``` , and ```df_implants['OPERTN_01'].str.contains('V011, V014', regex=True)``` - both come up with nothing found ( boolean of NaN). is there a way to filter when the records contain lists ?.

Comment: @capnahab the easiest thing to do would be to convert the list column to a string and then use [boolean indexing](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing). So , first convert `OPERTN_01 ` to a string like so `s = df_implants['OPERTN_01'].apply(str)` then use boolean indexing: `df_implants[(s == "['V011', 'V014']") | (s == "['V014', 'V011']")]`

Comment: @capnahab or it sounds like you want to filter `[V011, V014]` and `[V014, V011]` separately so you would do `v011v014 = df_implants[(s == "['V011', 'V014']")]` and then `v014v011 = df_implants[(s == "['V014', 'V011']")]`

Comment: Works wonderfully thanks, A couple of things got me - not splitting the list and the dfferent use of ' and " . Thanks. This is for all the operations in England to repair the skull (with the patients own bone or titanium implant), over 6 years, - Hopefully will find out which is best. You;ve been v helpfull in harnessing the data!.

Comment: @capnahab Glad I could help. This sound like some interesting work. Best of luck to you.