# Python set - how to filter for all combinations

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, set

I am a surgeon looking at data for patients who have had more than one operation for pituitary tumours.
I have 384 patients who have had 806 operations. Most of them have had 2 operations but some have had 3 or 4.
The operation codes for the two types of operation are B041 and B012.
I have used the method below to loop through the rows of my DataFrame to create an index of only those patients that had at least two different OPs of interest.

```
pit_codes = {'B041', 'B012'}
pit_index = []
for i in df_patients.index:
    """EDIT: filter criterion tightened to at least two different 
       relevant OPs, i.e. the intersection of the implant_codes 
       list with the patient's OP list has at least two elements."""
    if len(pit_codes.intersection(df_patients.OPERTN_01[i])) >= 2: 
        pit_index.append(i)

df_pits = df_patients.filter(pit_index, axis=0)
display(df_pits)
```

The dataframe this was looping through was a pivot table listing the operations.

```
df_patients = pd.pivot_table(dups_ind, index=dups_ind.index, aggfunc=list)
display(df_patients)
```

This has worked to some extent but the resulting datframe  `df_pits` has only 61 patients instead of 384.
Looking at the operation sequences -

```
df_pits.OPERTN_01.value_counts()
```

```
[B012, B041]                26
[B041, B012]                26
[B041, B012, B041]           4
[B041, B041, B012]           2
[B012, B012, B041, B041]     1
[B012, B041, B041]           1
[B041, B012, B012]           1
Name: OPERTN_01, dtype: int64
```

It seems that defining my set as `pit_codes = {'B041', 'B012'}` has not allowed for the majority of cases where patients get the same operation twice eg B041 then B041, or B012 then B012. (Tho I havent got around to proving this yet as my skills are minimal).
How can I create my set to pick up these operation sequences where the same operation is done twice?

Comment: Can you provide an example of the actual data frame please?

Comment: So you want to know with patients had at least the operations {'B041', 'B012'}? If you cannot provide the data a *dummy* example is enough

Answer (score 0):

I am only guessing what your data frame looks like, but here are some examples.

Initiate some example of a data frame

```
 > import pandas as pd
 > df = pd.DataFrame([{'Patient': 'patient1', 'Treatement': 'B012'},
     {'Patient': 'patient2', 'Treatement': 'B012'},
     {'Patient': 'patient2', 'Treatement': 'B012'},
     {'Patient': 'patient2', 'Treatement': 'B012'},
     {'Patient': 'patient2', 'Treatement': 'B012'},
     {'Patient': 'patient2', 'Treatement': 'B012'},
     {'Patient': 'patient2', 'Treatement': 'B012'},
     {'Patient': 'patient2', 'Treatement': 'B022'},
     {'Patient': 'patient2', 'Treatement': 'B022'},
     {'Patient': 'patient2', 'Treatement': 'B023'},
     {'Patient': 'patient2', 'Treatement': 'B041'},
     {'Patient': 'patient3', 'Treatement': 'B012'},
     {'Patient': 'patient4', 'Treatement': 'B041'},
     {'Patient': 'patient5', 'Treatement': 'B012'},
     {'Patient': 'patient6', 'Treatement': 'B041'},
     {'Patient': 'patient7', 'Treatement': 'B012'},
     {'Patient': 'patient8', 'Treatement': 'B012'},
     {'Patient': 'patient9', 'Treatement': 'B041'},
     {'Patient': 'patient2', 'Treatement': 'B041'},
     {'Patient': 'patient2', 'Treatement': 'B041'},
     {'Patient': 'patient2', 'Treatement': 'B041'},
     {'Patient': 'patient3', 'Treatement': 'B041'},
     {'Patient': 'patient4', 'Treatement': 'B012'},
     {'Patient': 'patient5', 'Treatement': 'B041'},
     {'Patient': 'patient6', 'Treatement': 'B041'},
     {'Patient': 'patient12', 'Treatement': 'B033'},
     {'Patient': 'patient11', 'Treatement': 'B049'}])
```

Group all patients & their treatements:

```
> df.groupby(['Patient','Treatement']).size()

patient1   B012          1
patient11  B049          1
patient12  B033          1
patient2   B012          6
           B022          2
           B023          1
           B041          4
patient3   B012          1
           B041          1
patient4   B012          1
           B041          1
patient5   B012          1
           B041          1
patient6   B041          2
patient7   B012          1
patient8   B012          1
patient9   B041          1
```

Define treatments we're interested in:

```
> pit_codes = ['B041', 'B012']
```

Apply the list as filter & initiate a second data frame (df2) for convenience.

```
> df2=df.query('Treatement == @pit_codes')
```

Print information per patient, per treatment (and count)

```
> df2.groupby(['Patient','Treatement']).size()

Patient   Treatement
patient1  B012          1
patient2  B012          6
          B041          4
patient3  B012          1
          B041          1
patient4  B012          1
          B041          1
patient5  B012          1
          B041          1
patient6  B041          2
patient7  B012          1
patient8  B012          1
patient9  B041          1
```

I hope that helps, but it's a bit tricky without knowing the actual dataframe.

Comment: Many thanks, - unfortunately the data has identifiable fields - I need to create an anonymous dataset. This method is helpful but ultimately I want to calculate the interval between operations so my method above does that but is not picking up the same operation twice which is something to do with the set.

Comment: Can you not provide some sample data? You can anonymise it. I just don't understand what's your table/dataframe structure.

Comment: I will get some anonymized data. I don't need a completely new method for doing this - I just want to know how to construct the set ``` pit_codes = {'B041', 'B012'} ``` so that it can identify two subsequent operations the same e.g. BO41 followed by BO41.Heres the original post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60884042/pandas-how-to-pick-events-by-date-and-create-a-new-ordered-dataframe-surger    Arne